# PHP echo table images in one row?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mysql

I have the following PHP block displaying images from my database. My problem is that I would like the images to display in a single ROW, to the point it overflows off the screen and the user is able to scroll left to right to look at all of the images. The current output from this code is that all of the images are being displayed all in a single cell and being shown in one COLUMN. How would I go about counting the row in my products page and portraying the next image in the next column accordingly? I want the images to display horizontally, not vertically.

```css
.table-outter {
    border:2px solid white;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.hype{
    border-collapse:collapse; 
    border:1px solid #777;
    padding:5px 10px; 
    height:250px; 
    text-align:center;
    min-width: 250px; 
}
.popup{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 900;    
}
#popup{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 75vh;
    background: white;
    opacity: .8;
    margin: auto;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 900;    
}
```

```html
<?php
//CONNECT TO database
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
//This block grabs the whole list for viewing
$dynamic_list = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 5");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);//count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $product_name = $row["product_name"];
        $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
        $dynamic_list .= '<table style="table-layout: fixed; margin:0px auto 0px auto; border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #777;">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="hype"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="250" height="250" border="1" /></a></td>

<td class="hype"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="250" height="250" border="1" /></a></td>

<td class="hype"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="250" height="250" border="1" /></a></td>

<td class="hype"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="250" height="250" border="1" /></a></td>

<td class="hype"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="250" height="250" border="1" /></a></td>

<td class="hype"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="250" height="250" border="1" /></a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>';
    }
} else{
    $dynamic_list = "There are no products listed in our store yet";
}
mysql_close();
?>
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="popup" id="popup">
              <div class="table-outter">
                <p>
                  <?php echo $dynamic_list; ?>
                </p>
              </div>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you use the code multiple times to output images

I think you don't need a table for it, right ?

I think you can use the `for` statement for this :
`$count` to store number of images

```
for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) { 
  $list = '<a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="250" height="250" border="1" /></a>'
}
```

Comment: Good point, but this does not answer the question. This should be placed as comment instead, not an answer.

Comment: @FlameDenise I'm sorry I think it may help as answer